# Retrieving 52 weeks after the result of a subquery

Tags: sql, teradata

From a table that contains sales, I retrieved the last week of that table. That gives me the last week where there are sales being made. 'Date' is always the first day of the month but it doesn't matter, the real important data is week and partial_week.
The result is simple :

```
+------------+---------+--------------+
|    Date    |  Week   | Partial_week |
+------------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-02-01 | 2020-09 | 2020M02W09   |
+------------+---------+--------------+
```

Let's call it t1

I have a table with the first day of each month, every week and partial week from 2015 to 2025
(when a week is on two months, it's split in two partial weeks that have the same number but different month). It looks like this :

```
+------------+---------+--------------+
|    Date    |  Week   | Partial_week |
+------------+---------+--------------+
| 2020-02-01 | 2020-05 | 2020M02W05   |
| 2020-02-01 | 2020-06 | 2020M02W06   |
| 2020-02-01 | 2020-07 | 2020M02W07   |
| 2020-02-01 | 2020-08 | 2020M02W08   |
| 2020-02-01 | 2020-09 | 2020M02W09   |
| 2020-03-01 | 2020-09 | 2020M03W09   |
+------------+---------+--------------+
```

Let's call it t2

I now need to retrieve everything in t2 that is between 1 et 52 weeks after my week retrieved in t1. (this should get me every weeks and partial weeks until 2021-09 or so).

I tought about having a

'select top 52 distinct week from t2'

joining on t1 and having a where clause 'where t1.week < t2.week'

then joining everything on t2 again to get every partial week too,

but that doesn't work because on every week t1.week is equal to null (I wish t1.week could just be a variable since it only has one row...)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems to be close. Put the initial query in a Scalar Subquery to handle it like a variable:

```
select *
from t2 
where t2.week >=
 ( select week from t1 -- i.e. your existing query to return the latest week 
 )
qualify 
   dense_rank()
   over (order by week) <= 52
```

You can also switch to a join:

```
select *
from t2 
join
 ( select week from t1 -- i.e. your existing query to return the latest week 
 ) as t1
on t2.week >= t1.week 
qualify 
   dense_rank() -- next 52 week & partial weeks
   over (order by t2.week) <= 52
```

Explain of the Scalar Subquery might be better.

Comment: With a few tweaks, the first solution you proposed worked like a charm ;) Thank you so much, I'll have to learn more about Scalar subqueries now.